# openlayer3 vector layer text display repeated

Tags: openlayers-3

[This is a picture which shows the number of my shops at this place, but why on my map the number 90 is repeated?. I am using a styleFunc to determine the color, the cold is something like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXNwv.png)

```
 function styleFunction(feature) {
            var destCount = feature.get("destCount");
            var originCount = feature.get("originCount");
            if (typeof originCount === "undefined") {
                originCount = 0;
            }
            if (typeof destCount === "undefined") {
                destCount = 0;
            }
            totalPointsCount = destCount + originCount;
            totalPointsCount = totalPointsCount.toString();
            return getStyle(feature.getProperties().type);
        }

function styleFunction(feature) {
            var destCount = feature.get("destCount");
            var originCount = feature.get("originCount");
            if (typeof originCount === "undefined") {
                originCount = 0;
            }
            if (typeof destCount === "undefined") {
                destCount = 0;
            }
            totalPointsCount = destCount + originCount;
            totalPointsCount = totalPointsCount.toString();
            return getStyle(feature.getProperties().type);
        }
```

Code for creating the baseLayer is:

```
fetch('data/xml/service-meta-data.xml').then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function (text) {
        var result = parser.read(text);
        var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
            layer: 'China',
            matrixSet: 'EPSG:3857'
        });
        var baseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            opacity: 1,
            source: new ol.source.WMTS(options)
        });
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
                baseLayer,
                vectorLayer
            ],
            overlays: [infoOverlay],
            target: 'map',
            view: view
        });
     })
```

You can ignore all the data processing, and focus on the stylefunc, can anyone tell me why the number is repeated? Many thxs

Comment: Just click the link above to see the attachment

Comment: This problem occurs when you are publishing layer as TileWMS. Can you post the code that creates the layer?

Comment: Simple version of code creating the map base layer is sth like what is shown above, how can I solve the problem here?

Comment: I think I find where the problem is, coordination of the repeated number area is a multipolygon, and i think this is the reason, but when I change the coordination into a polygon, ol.js tells me there is sth wrong

Comment: Oh, Yeah, it is because the data model, I finally know the reason.........

Answer (score 0):

Have a look this link [Openlayers3 Vector labels](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html).

Tile layers create duplicate labels when you start zooming in. So create it has ImageWMS layer.

```
    var baseLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        opacity: 1,
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS(options)
    });
```